# No module named 'pyparsing' when executing "poetry install" on Azure pipelines

Tags: python, windows, azure-pipelines, python-poetry

First of all, I'm not sure whether this is a problem of Windows, poetry, or pyparsing, as I don't have a Windows environment to reproduce this error.

But here's what happens when I run my tests on Azure pipelines:

https://dev.azure.com/laike9m/laike9m/_build/results?buildId=2

I'm using `poetry` to manage my dependecies, when executing `poetry install`, an error occurred:

```
[ModuleNotFoundError]  

No module named 'pyparsing'         

...

 c:\hostedtoolcache\windows\python\3.7.3\x64\lib\site-packages\poetry\utils\env.py in <module>() at line 25

   from poetry.version.markers import BaseMarker

 c:\hostedtoolcache\windows\python\3.7.3\x64\lib\site-packages\poetry\version\markers.py in <module>() at line 3

   from pyparsing import ParseException, ParseResults, stringStart, stringEnd
```

However, previous log shows `pyparsing` has been successfully installed.

My config file for Azure pipelines is here

https://github.com/laike9m/Cyberbrain/blob/master/azure-pipelines.yml

Somehow this error only happens for Win + Python3.7, but passes on Win + Python3.6, and on Linux and OSX.

Comment: maybe you have two Pythons and one has installed `pyparsing` but you run other Python.

Comment: It looks like your `pyparsing` is installed for `D:\a\1\s\.tox\py37\Scripts\python.EXE` but you are using system-wide Python after.

Comment: @Sraw Thank you, that seems to be the direct cause. Still trying to locate root cause.

Comment: You are welcome. Doubtlessly using system-wide Python is not the expected behavior, solving this should fix the problem :)

Comment: Since this is essentially a config/environment problem, could you please remove the [pyparsing] tag?

Comment: @PaulMcG removed